# is there a way to reload hasura remote schema using nodejs

Tags: node.js, graphql, express-graphql, hasura

I'm setting up a remote schema inside the other **hasura** **graphql** schema how can I set up the **reload_remote_schema** using node/express js?

I'm facing below problem.
Graphql remote schema data is not updating before clicking on the reload button. I don't want to reload remote schema manually, it should refresh automatically via node/express js code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With any JS http client, you should be able to hit this endpoint:

```
POST /v1/query HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
X-Hasura-Role: admin

{
    "type": "reload_remote_schema",
    "args": {
        "name": "my remote schema"
    }
}
```

Documentation: https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/api-reference/schema-metadata-api/remote-schemas.html#reload-remote-schema

Any time you update your remote schema (e.g. on a new deploy), you can refresh via API.

It's also possible to refresh your remote schemas via CLI: https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/hasura-cli/hasura_metadata_reload.html#hasura-metadata-reload. But this operation is an exclusive/expensive request (with potential to cause deadlocks as of beta.3 at least).

Comment: The hasura cli command metadata reload does not reload remote schemas. When making the request `reload_remote_schemas` is not set hence defaults to false and there is no option via cli to set it when making the request